# list of checkbox “true,false” value MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<RolesMVC3.Models.Estudent>
.
.
.
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    { 
              <tr>
                <td> @Html.CheckBox("CheckValue")</td>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CodeEstudent)  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].IdEstudent)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].NameEstudent)  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastNameEstudent)</td>
            </tr>     
     }
.
.
.
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyController(List<ESTUDENT> estudents, List<bool> CheckValue)
    {

        ///Actions
    }
```

But, I reciveb two CheckBox for each student.

e.g. I am sending 29 and receive 58 in the controller

How do I associate a CheckBox with a student on this list and get in the controller?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to understand how ASP.NET MVC render checkbox:

```
<input id="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="RememberMe" />
```

How it works? Form always submit `hidden` field and submit `type="checkbox"` only if it was checked, then binder look's at the type (`bool`) and if there is two values it set `true`, else `false`.

In your example you need to set `index` for `CheckBox`, so you will send 29 pairs of data, not 58 independent values.

More details:

- [Binding to a collection of CheckboxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470391/binding-to-a-collection-of-checkboxfor)
- [Is there any way to bind a checkbox list to a model in asp.net
  mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888615/is-there-any-way-to-bind-a-checkbox-list-to-a-model-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [How to bind CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557897/how-to-bind-checkboxfor)